# Retain line breaks when saving from textarea to localStorage

Tags: javascript, jquery, textarea, local-storage, newline

I have a website which lets you write text in `<textarea>s`

Every second, it is saved to `localStorage`

When the user comes back to the website, the `localStorage` is loaded and inserted into the `<textarea>`

*Note: The javascript code below is jQuery.*

```
setInterval( function() {
    var currentDoc = $("textarea").val();
    localStorage.savedDoc = currentDoc;
}, 1000);

$(document).ready( function() {
    var savedDoc = localStorage.savedDoc;
    $("textarea").val(savedDoc);
});
```

Line breaks (new lines) are not retained, however.

Is there a way to save line breaks so they reload properly?

Comment: Looks good http://jsfiddle.net/5U6Nq/

Comment: Hav you tried `JSON.stringify`ing the data

Comment: @Xotic750 Stringify what? String?

Comment: I don't believe that you should need to, but there always a chance there is a bug in whatever browser you are trying with. I mean @ user3002189

Comment: So more details needed. In demo I set up, everything is working.

Comment: Yes, more information required.